# Calculate time difference for consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me with a SQL query as per my below requirement?
I have a table like this.

```
S_ID      S_ACTV_CODE   S_USER  S_DATETIME            S_ACT_IND
AAA-111   NULL          USER1   2015-06-15 00:21:06   0
AAA-111   2             USER1   2015-06-15 00:21:07   0
AAA-111   2             USER1   2015-06-15 00:25:12   0
AAA-111   4             USER2   2015-06-17 03:20:33   0
AAA-111   3             USER1   2015-06-17 03:43:25   0
AAA-111   4             USER3   2015-06-22 05:02:37   0
AAA-111   4             USER4   2015-06-23 05:25:05   1
AAA-112   NULL          USER4   2015-06-25 11:11:11   0
AAA-112   4             USER3   2015-06-25 11:11:12   0
AAA-112   4             USER4   2015-06-26 20:25:49   0
AAA-112   4             USER2   2015-06-29 18:04:32   1
AAA-113   NULL          USER2   2015-06-24 07:10:37   0
AAA-113   NULL          USER1   2015-06-24 07:10:41   0
AAA-113   3             USER1   2015-06-24 07:10:43   1
```

Basically I want to calculate the time spent by S_Users on a particular S_ACTV_CODE:

- S_ACTV_CODE_PREV means the previous active records.
- S_START_TIME is the time of S_DATETIME when a S_ACTV_CODE starts
- S_END_TIME is the time before a S_ACTV_CODE changes to another S_ACTV_CODE
- For the first record, S_ACTV_CODE is null, so there is no S_ACTV_CODE_PREV, so S_ACTV_CODE_PREV is NULL
- For the second record S_ACTV_CODE has some value, but S_ACTV_CODE_PREV is NULL for first record. So second record
  S_ACTV_CODE_PREV is also NULL
- For the last record (means S_ACTV_IND = 1), the user is currently working on it and S_ACTV_CODE is not changed. So S_END_TIME is a open
  time and we want to keep it as NULL

So the result should be as below:

```
S_ID      S_ACTV_CODE_PREV  S_ACTV_CODE_CURR  S_USER  S_START_TIME         S_END_TIME             TIME_SPENT (in Sec)
AAA-111   NULL              NULL              USER1   2015-06-15 00:21:06  2015-06-15 00:21:07    1
AAA-111   NULL              2                 USER1   2015-06-15 00:21:07  2015-06-17 03:20:33    183566
AAA-111   2                 4                 USER2   2015-06-17 03:20:33  2015-06-17 03:43:25    1372
AAA-111   4                 3                 USER3   2015-06-17 03:43:25  2015-06-22 05:02:37    436752
AAA-111   3                 4                 USER4   2015-06-22 05:02:37  NULL                   NULL
AAA-112   NULL              NULL              USER4   2015-06-25 11:11:11  2015-06-25 11:11:12    1
AAA-112   NULL              4                 USER3   2015-06-25 11:11:12  NULL                   NULL
AAA-113   NULL              NULL              USER2   2015-06-24 07:10:37  2015-06-24 07:10:43    6
AAA-113   NULL              3                 USER1   2015-06-24 07:10:43  NULL                   NULL
```

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, etc) are you using?

Comment: It's in SQL Server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do S_START_TIME and S_END_TIME come from?

Comment: As mentioned in my requirement,  S_START_TIME and S_END_TIME should be derived from S_DATETIME.

Comment: -- S_START_TIME is the time of S_DATETIME when a S_ACTV_CODE starts
-- S_END_TIME is the time before a S_ACTV_CODE changes to another S_ACTV_CODE

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with  Rank & Lag functions but couldn't succeed

Comment: I changed the title to better reflect what the question is about - I hope I correctly reflected your intent.

Answer (score 3):

Re-wrote the SQL to get the first date and last user for the rows. It made it quite more ugly, but this should work:

```
select
  s_id,
  lag(s_actv_code, 1) over (partition by s_id order by s_datetime asc) as s_actv_code_prev,
  s_actv_code,
  s_user,
  s_datetime as start_time,
  lead(s_datetime, 1) over (partition by s_id order by s_datetime asc) as end_time,
  datediff (second, s_datetime,
    lead(s_datetime, 1) over (partition by s_id order by s_datetime asc)) as duration 
from
(
  select distinct
  s_id,
  S_ACTV_CODE,
  last_value(s_user)
  over (partition by s_id, S_ACTV_CODE, GRP 
        order by S_datetime asc
        rows between current row and unbounded following) as s_user,
  first_value(s_datetime)
  over (partition by s_id, S_ACTV_CODE, GRP 
        order by S_datetime asc
        ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ) as s_datetime
   from (
     select
       *,
       row_number() over (partition by s_id order by s_datetime asc) -
       row_number() over (partition by s_id, s_actv_code order by s_datetime asc) as GRP
     from
       table1
   ) X
) Y
order by s_id, start_time
```

Edit: Added partition by s_id due to new changes to example.

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97c09/3)

Comment: Actually there seems to be wrong user shown in the last row, since it takes it from the start row of the activity, not from the last one.

Comment: Yes. Except the User issue, it is giving the correct result. At the moment the wrong User is getting displayed

Comment: @Rupa I re-wrote the fetch using first_value / last_value, now it returns the correct result

Comment: Hi James, It is giving correct result except in S_User column - User3. Instead of User3, it is displaying User1 at the moment. Rest everything is fine.

Comment: @Rupa For activity 3? That must be problem in your expected results because you don't have that row in your data at all.

Comment: Hi James, sorry to bother you again. The query you gave me is working for records with single S_ID only. When multiple records with multiple S_IDs it is not working. Can you please look into this again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rupa Could you edit that into the question, without knowing what you actually expect I don't really know how to change it

Comment: Hi James, I have updated my requirement and expected result in topic. Please follow the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Rupa Added partition bys to the select

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies. I have updated the query below way.

```
SELECT
S_ID,
LAG(S_ACTV_CODE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY S_DATETIME ASC) AS S_ACTV_CODE_PREV,
S_ACTV_CODE,
S_USER,
S_DATETIME AS START_TIME,
LEAD(S_DATETIME, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY S_DATETIME ASC) AS END_TIME,
DATEDIFF (SECOND, S_DATETIME,
LEAD(S_DATETIME, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY S_DATETIME ASC)) AS DURATION 
FROM (
SELECT
S_ID,
LAG(S_ACTV_CODE, 1, 'N/A') OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY S_DATETIME ASC) AS S_ACTV_CODE_PREV,
S_ACTV_CODE,
S_USER,
S_DATETIME
FROM TABLE1
) X WHERE ISNULL(S_ACTV_CODE_PREV,'') != ISNULL(S_ACTV_CODE,'')
ORDER BY S_ID, START_TIME;
```

The above query worked for me and gave the expected results. Thanks once again for all your replies.

Comment: But this gives the wrong user to the row AAA-111, 3, 4